# Parallelizing Boruvka with openMP

Tags: c++, algorithm, openmp

I have implemented Boruvka's algorithm sequentially in C++ and I know one of the advantages of the algorithm is that it can easily be paralleled. I am trying to do this using openMP, but I can't figure out how to get it to work. I read in an adjacency list from graph.txt and print my output of the minimum spanning tree into mst.txt. Here is my sequential code for boruvka:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;

// initialize data structure for edges (given in adjacency list)
struct Edge {
    int v1, v2, weight; // 2 connecting verticies and a weight
};

// initialize structure for the graph
struct Graph {
   int vertex, edge;
   Edge* e; // undirected graph so edge from v1 to v2 is same as v2 to v1
};

// Creates a graph for #verticies and #edges using arrays
struct Graph* formGraph(int vertex, int edge)
{
    Graph* graph = new Graph;
    graph->vertex = vertex;
    graph->edge = edge;
    graph->e = new Edge[edge]; // again, v1-v2 = v2-v1
    return graph;
}

// initialize structure for subsets within the graph
struct Subset {
    int parent, rank; // rank will act as counter
};

// will help to find lightest edge of sets recursively
int find(struct Subset subset[], int i)
{
    if (subset[i].parent != i) {
        subset[i].parent = find(subset, subset[i].parent);
    }
 // once it is =1
 return subset[i].parent;
 }

// A function that does union of two sets
void Union(struct Subset subs[], int set1, int set2)
{
    int root1 = find(subs, set1);
    int root2 = find(subs, set2);

    //union by ranking
    if (subs[root1].rank < subs[root2].rank) { // if rank2 is higher thats parent
        subs[root1].parent = root2;
    }

    else if (subs[root1].rank > subs[root2].rank) { // if rank1 is higher thats parent
        subs[root2].parent = root1;
    }

    else // ranks are the equal so increment rank by 1
    {
        subs[root2].parent = root1;
        subs[root1].rank++;
    }
}

// the boruvka algorithm implementation
void boruvka(struct Graph* graph) {
// set data of initial graph
int vertex = graph->vertex;
int edge = graph->edge;
Edge* e = graph->e;

//initially there will always be as many subsets as there are vertices
struct Subset *subs = new Subset[vertex];

int *lightest = new int[vertex]; // array storing least weight edge

// subset for each vertex
for (int v = 0; v < vertex; v++)
{
    subs[v].parent = v; // initial parent (none)
    subs[v].rank = 0; // initial rank (no parent so always 0)
    lightest[v] = -1; // start from -1
}

int components = vertex; // iniitial trees = number of verticies
int minWeight = 0;

// must keep going until there is only one tree
while (components > 1)
{
    // lightest weight for all edges
    for (int i=0; i<edge; i++)
    {
        // gets subsets for edges that could connect
        int set1 = find(subs, e[i].v1);
        int set2 = find(subs, e[i].v2);

        // waste of time if they're already in same set so don't check
        if (set1 == set2)
            continue;

        // if different then check which one is lightest
        else
        {
            if (lightest[set1] == -1 || e[lightest[set1]].weight > e[i].weight) {
                lightest[set1] = i;
            }

            if (lightest[set2] == -1 || e[lightest[set2]].weight > e[i].weight) {
                lightest[set2] = i;
            }
        }
    }

    // making sure the wieghts are added
    for (int i=0; i<vertex; i++)
    {
        // make sure all lightest edges are included
        if (lightest[i] != -1)
        {
            int s1 = find(subs, e[lightest[i]].v1);
            int s2 = find(subs, e[lightest[i]].v2);

            if (s1 == s2)
                continue;

            minWeight += e[lightest[i]].weight;

            // Need to sort output lexicographically!?!?!?!?!!
            printf("Edge %d-%d included in MST with weight %d\n", // prints verices and weight of edge
                   e[lightest[i]].v1, e[lightest[i]].v2,
                   e[lightest[i]].weight);

            // union subsets together, decrease component number
            Union(subs, s1, s2);
            components--;
        }
        lightest[i] = -1; // in case after first iteration lightest edges fall in same subset
     }

}

printf("Weight of MST is %d\n", minWeight);
return;
}

// main function for calling boruvka
int main() {
    ifstream infile;
    char inputFileName[] = "graph.txt"; // input filename here
    infile.open(inputFileName, ios::in);

    string line;

    getline(infile, line);
    int V = atoi(line.c_str()); // set num of vertices to first line of txt

    getline(infile, line);
    int E = atoi(line.c_str()); // set num of edges to second line of txt

    // create graph for boruvka
    struct Graph* graph = formGraph(V, E);

    if (infile.is_open()) {
        string data[3]; // initialize data array
        int count = 0; // initialize counter

        while (infile.good()) { // same as while not end of file
            getline(infile, line);
            stringstream ssin(line);
            int i = 0;

        while (ssin.good() && i < 3) {
            ssin >> data[i];
            i++;
        }

            graph->e[count].v1 = atoi(data[0].c_str());
            graph->e[count].v2 = atoi(data[1].c_str());
            graph->e[count].weight = atoi(data[2].c_str());

        count++;
    }
}

freopen("mst.txt","w",stdout); // writes output into mst.txt

// call boruvka function
boruvka(graph);

infile.close(); // close the input file
return 0;
}
```

An example of my graph.txt is this:

```
9
14
0 1 4
7 8 7
1 2 8
1 7 11
2 3 7
2 5 4
2 8 2
3 4 9
3 5 14
4 5 10
5 6 2
6 7 1
6 8 6
0 7 8
```

The output for this example which is correct that is placed in my mst.txt is this:

```
Edge 0-1 included in MST with weight 4
Edge 2-8 included in MST with weight 2
Edge 2-3 included in MST with weight 7
Edge 3-4 included in MST with weight 9
Edge 5-6 included in MST with weight 2
Edge 6-7 included in MST with weight 1
Edge 1-2 included in MST with weight 8
Edge 2-5 included in MST with weight 4
Weight of MST is 37
```

Comment: So what is the expected output? Vs what do you actually get? What have you tried so far to fix the problem?

Comment: @Jesper Juhl right now the input is an adjeceny list with the first line being total number of vertices, the second line is total number of edges and then the rest is v1 v2 weight. All 3 of those per line for however many edges there are. My output prints out the correct answer in the form of giving the vertices and weight and then the last line gives me the total weight for the spanning tree

Answer (score 0):

According to the algorithm, in each iteration, each tree in the forest will have one and only one edge added to the forest independently (edges from different trees could be the same), until the added edges connect the whole forest into a single tree.

Here you can see finding the only edge for each tree can be done in parallel. As long as you have more than one tree, you could use multiple threads to speed up the searching.

Answer (score 0):

if you're interested, I've written an [implementation](https://github.com/abarankab/parallel_boruvka/) of the parallel Boruvka's algorithm using OpenMP.

We store the graph as an edge list (`edges`) where each edge `(u, v)` appears twice: as an edge from `u` and from `v`. At each step of the algorithm, edges is sorted in `O(E log E) = O(E log V)` time.

Then edges are split between `P` processors. Each one of them calculates the array of shortest edges from its local nodes. Because allocating raw memory for all nodes is done in constant time, we can simply store this as an array and avoid using hashmaps. Then we merge the results between processors into a global shortest edge array using compare and swap. Note that because we sorted the edge list previously, all edges from `u` make up a continuous segment in edges. Because of this, the total number of extra iterations in the cas loop does not exceed `O(P)` which gives us `O(E / P + P) = O(E / P)` time for this step.

After that, we can merge components along the added edges in `O(V * alpha(V) / P)` time using a parallel DSU algorithm.

The next step is updating the list of vertices and edges, this can be done using parallel cumulative sum in `O(V / P)` and `O(E / P)` respectively.

Since the total number of iterations is `O(log V)`, the overall time complexity is `O(E log^2 V / P)`.